# How to remove the suffix number in the column names in data frame in R

Tags: r, quantmod, yahoo-finance

I have a problem while I am downloading the data from yahoo finance using quantmod. There are always a suffix number after the column ticker names that I want to remove.

My code as follow:

```
library("quantmod")
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
library("FinancialInstrument")

myenv <- new.env()
tickers <- c("LNKD", "FB", "HP", "AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG", "EBAY")
getSymbols(tickers, env = myenv)
monthly.Return <- do.call(merge, c(eapply(myenv, monthlyReturn), all=FALSE))
names(monthly.Return)[1:10] <- paste(tickers, 1:10, sep="")
monthly.Return
```

The output:

```
LNKD1          FB2           HP3         AAPL4        MSFT5        GOOG6       EBAY7
2012-05-31 -0.117267081 -0.044978166 -0.0446123842 -0.0107024213 -0.118505546 -0.039662726 -0.11387736
2012-06-29  0.072333240  0.051668953  0.0719571319  0.0108528205 -0.040176600 -0.001360052  0.10582726
2012-07-31  0.039632546  0.045217391  0.0545108308  0.0458219178  0.069457222  0.091195890 -0.03406418
................................
```

And I want to remove the number after each column names.

Comment: I get an error with the getSymbols call. I suspect that you have not given us all of the needed libraries or this is a proprietary data server.

Comment: It just needs the quantmod package I think.

Comment: Think again. I have the quantmod package loaded. getSymbols(tickers, env = myenv)
Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT&a=0&b=01&c=2007&d=10&e=21&f=2013&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=MSFT&x=.csv'

Comment: I am not sure which package we need in this code, so I uploaded all the package I have to the above code.

Comment: After loading Performance Analytics (my first guess) I no longer get an error with getSymbols. I still get an error. And it comes from: `names(monthly.Return)[1:10] <- paste(tickers, 1:10, sep="")`

Comment: If I use: `names(monthly.Return)[1:7] <- paste(tickers, 1:7, sep="")` I get no error  ... not too surprising in light of only 7 elements in tickers, eh?

Comment: Oh, sorry for that, but even I put 7 instead of 10 there, gsub("(.*)[0-9]+?", "\\1", x) made no changes, and the suffix number still exists.

Comment: That's Chinmay's solution and I don't understand it. I would just delete all the digits as illustrated.

Comment: @DWin I thought OP wanted to remove only the digits at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> names(monthly.Return)
[1] "LNKD1" "FB2"   "HP3"   "AAPL4" "MSFT5" "GOOG6" "EBAY7"
> names(monthly.Return) <- gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", names(monthly.Return) )
> names(monthly.Return)
[1] "LNKD" "FB"   "HP"   "AAPL" "MSFT" "GOOG" "EBAY"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
x
##  [1] "LNKD1" "FB2"   "HP3"   "AAPL4" "MSFT5" "GOOG6" "EBAY7" "LNKD8" "FB9"   "HP10" 

gsub("(.*)[0-9]+?", "\\1", x)
##  [1] "LNKD" "FB"   "HP"   "AAPL" "MSFT" "GOOG" "EBAY" "LNKD" "FB"   "HP"
```

Comment: names(monthly.Return) <- gsub("(.*)[0-9]*", "\\1", x),  it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This removes trailing/ending Number but not the numbers in between

```
 names(monthly.Return)
 names(monthly.Return) <- gsub("[0-9]$", "", names(monthly.Return) )
 names(monthly.Return)
```

If you have more than one digit in the end then :

```
 names(monthly.Return)
 names(monthly.Return) <- gsub("[0-9]$|[0-9][0-9]$", "", names(monthly.Return) )
 names(monthly.Return)
```